# Scroll bar, but there's no content

Tags: html, css

My website has no content up or down yet the scroll bar is visible and lets you scroll.

Unfortunately I don't know what would cause I'm assuming it something to do with this CSS code, but I honestly don't know.

```
html, body
{
    height:100%;
}
.centre
{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
}
#wrapper {
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    min-height:600px;
    min-width:600px;
}
```

Everything on the website is based off the centre class. And `<div id="wrapper"></div>` surrounds all the content.

I know I haven't been very helpful but from my understanding there should only be scroll bars if there is content outside the view-able area and there isn't.

Comment: Reset your default and it solves `* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}`

Comment: +1 at least for the incredible funny discussion on your question.

Comment: Agree with Linus. :D Awesome how sometimes simple questions create so much revolt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either remove the `height: 100%` from `<html/>`, `<body/>` and `#wrapper` or add

```
html, body { margin: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this CSS to your stylesheet:

```
body {margin:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set `body` margins to zero:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Normally browser set a default value for the body.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a reset **on top** of your CSS. In other words, this should be the first line:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; outline: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to reset the `default styles` of the `document(browser default styles)`.To do this, add the following code to the top of the `css` file.

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Credit [LINK](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)